# How to assign AAD Group to an Enterprise App?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

i would like to know how to assign one or multiple groups to an application?

I've tried this but im getting an error:
Get-AzureADGroup : Error occurred while executing GetGroup

```
connect-azuread

$GroupName = "TEST"
$app_name = "Intranet"
$app_role_name = "Default Access"

# Get the group to assign
$AADGROUP = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $GroupName
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$app_name'"
$appRole = $sp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $app_role_name }

# Assign the group to the app role
New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $AADGROUP.ObjectId -PrincipalId $AADGROUP.ObjectId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $appRole.Id
```

Comment: I am unable to get a Role ID for "Default Access" no matter what I do. Even if I put an empty guid ([guid]::Empty.Guid) it still doesn't work. Did you not have a problem with the empty guid for "Default Access"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error indicate clearly the part which is failing.
There is no `ObjectId` provided to the last statement because your `$AADGroup.ObjectId` is `$null`

**Looking at an excerpt of your code:**

```
$GroupName = 'test'
$AADGROUP = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $GroupName
#...
# Assign the group to the app role
New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $AADGROUP.ObjectId -PrincipalId $AADGROUP.ObjectId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $appRole.Id
```

`$GroupName` is a very bad name for this variable if you are using it along with the `Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $GroupName` statement right after. It won't work. `-ObjectId` is expecting the object ID GUID of the group, not its name (You might be already doing it correctly, my assumption come from your variable name).

That would explain where you don't have any group returned and why the error occur.
If you want to use the group name, you will need to call the `Get-AzureADGroup` with `-SearchString` instead of `-ObjectId`.

Comment: nvm.. i found the error... i changed for get-azureadgroup -searchstring $groupname instead and it works fine thanks